How to make ResourceFunction["GeneralizedMapThread"] not go inside Association?
I really like the ResourceFunction["GeneralizedMapThread"]. It seems to work so far as I expected except now I encountered a case where it is causing me issues:
Initially I went for a regular MapThread:
MapThread[Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))/@{f,g,h},
    {<|"Major"-><|"x"->1,"y"->2|>,"Minor"-><|"x"->3,"y"->4|>|>,<|"Major"-><|"x"->5,"y"->6|>,"Minor"-><|"x"->7,"y"->8|>|>,<|"Major"-><|"x"->9,"y"->10|>,"Minor"-><|"x"->11,"y"->12|>|>}
}];
MapThread[Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))/@{f,g,h},
    {<|"Major"->1,"Minor"->2|>,<|"Major"->3,"Minor"->4|>,<|"Major"->5,"Minor"->6|>}
}];
MapThread[Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))/@{f,g,h},
    {<|"x"->1,"y"->2|>,<|"x"->3,"y"->4|>,<|"x"->5,"y"->6|>}
}];
MapThread[Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))/@{f,g,h},
    {1,2,3}
}];

MapThread[Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))/@{f},
    {<|"Major"-><|"x"->1,"y"->2|>,"Minor"-><|"x"->3,"y"->4|>|>}
}];
MapThread[Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))/@{f},
    {<|"Major"->1,"Minor"->2|>}
}];
MapThread[Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))/@{f},
    {<|"x"->1,"y"->2|>}
}];
MapThread[Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))/@{f},
    {1}
}];

All the above multifunction maps work fine, including the singleton version of a single function. But since the function can also arrive without a list, so I switched to ResourceFunction["GeneralizedMapThread"] to make it work.
ResourceFunction["GeneralizedMapThread"][Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))@f,
    1
}];

But the other variations are not working:
ResourceFunction["GeneralizedMapThread"][Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))@f,
    <|"Major"-><|"x"->1,"y"->2|>,"Minor"-><|"x"->3,"y"->4|>|>
}];
ResourceFunction["GeneralizedMapThread"][Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))@f,
    <|"Major"->1,"Minor"->2|>
}];
ResourceFunction["GeneralizedMapThread"][Construct,{
    (function|->(Map[function,#,{-1}]&))@f,
    <|"x"->1,"y"->2|>
}];

I was looking at the source code for the resource ResourceFunction["GeneralizedMapThread"]:
ClearAll[iListOrAssociation, GeneralizedMapThread]
iListOrAssociation[p_] := ListQ[p] \[Or] AssociationQ[p];
GeneralizedMapThread[f_, lsts_List, n_Integer?NonNegative] := 
 Module[{newlists, len},
  If[n == 0,
   Apply[f, lsts]
   ,
   len = Max[Length /@ Select[lsts, iListOrAssociation], 1];
   newlists = Table[
     If[Length[lst] == len \[And] iListOrAssociation[lst],
      lst
      ,
      ConstantArray[lst, len]
      ]
     ,
     {lst, lsts}
     ];
   MapThread[GeneralizedMapThread[f, {##}, n - 1] &, newlists]
   ]
  ]
GeneralizedMapThread[f_, lsts_] := GeneralizedMapThread[f, lsts, 1]
GeneralizedMapThread[f_][lsts_] := GeneralizedMapThread[f, lsts]

Can someone please help fix it so it would work on the last three cases too. Please help!

This solution makes use of function attribute Listable to simplify the implementation.
ClearAll[applyfunc]
SetAttributes[applyfunc, Listable]
applyfunc[f_, expr_] := Map[f, expr, {-1}]

Then the 4 cases you require from the OP are supported.
applyfunc[{f}, {<|"Major" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> 3, "y" -> 4|>|>}]


{<|"Major" -> <|"x" -> f[1], "y" -> f[2]|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> f[3], "y" -> f[4]|>|>}


And
applyfunc[
 {f, g, h}
 , {
     <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> 3, "y" -> 4|>|>
   , <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> 5, "y" -> 6|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> 7, "y" -> 8|>|>
   , <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> 9, "y" -> 10|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> 11, "y" -> 12|>|>
   }
 ]


{ 
   <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> f[1], "y" -> f[2]|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> f[3], "y" -> f[4]|>|>
 , <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> g[5], "y" -> g[6]|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> g[7], "y" -> g[8]|>|>
 , <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> h[9], "y" -> h[10]|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> h[11], "y" -> h[12]|>|>
}


And
applyfunc[{f}, {1}]


{f[1]}


And
applyfunc[f, 1]


f[1]


Note that you also get additional functionality of applying a function not in a list to a list of parameters.
applyfunc[
 f
 , {
     <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> 3, "y" -> 4|>|>
   , <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> 9, "y" -> 10|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> 11, "y" -> 12|>|>
   }
 ]


{
   <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> f[1], "y" -> f[2]|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> f[3], "y" -> f[4]|>|>
 , <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> f[9], "y" -> f[10]|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> f[11], "y" -> f[12]|>|>
}


And applying a list of functions to a parameter not in a list.
applyfunc[{f, g}, <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> 1, "y" -> 2|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> 3, "y" -> 4|>|>]


{
   <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> f[1], "y" -> f[2]|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> f[3], "y" -> f[4]|>|>
 , <|"Major" -> <|"x" -> g[1], "y" -> g[2]|>, "Minor" -> <|"x" -> g[3], "y" -> g[4]|>|>
}


Hope this helps.
